# Calculating zero-point energy for the Varshini potential

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry

As per my understanding, for a harmonic oscillator, we can find the zero-point energy by the relation below:

$$ E_0 = \left(0 + \frac{1}{2}\right)\hbar \omega$$

The equation for the potential in question is:

$$ V(x) = D_e \left(1 - \frac{r_e}{x} e^{-\alpha(x^2-r_e^2)}\right)^2 + T_e$$

How would one go about finding the value of $E_0$ for this potential surface?

Edit: All values aside from $x$ are known.

Comment: Can you explain what these symbols mean...?

Comment: You should look at the paper by Varshini in Reviews of Modern Physics, vol 29, 664 1957 where this function is described for diatomic molecules along with many others.